# Sendinblue/Brevo : 2 HTML-Forms interfere with each other

Tags: ajax, forms, submit, sendinblue

I have integrated 2 BREVO Forms (HTML/ajax type) in one of my webpage:

```
<form id="sib-form" method="POST" action="https://45ff9c8b.sibforms.com/serve/MUXXXX" data-type="subscription">
```

After having filled the 2 input fields EMAIL and FIRSTNAME of the **second Form**, then having clicked on its submit-button,

The input-field EMAIL of the **first Form** displays an error: "must be filled".
[image]

After having inspected the code in the script contained at the bottom of the provided copy/paste HTML-FORM in Brevo:

```
<script defer="defer" src="https://sibforms.com/forms/end-form/build/main.js"></script>
```

The error seems to be caused by the Selection By Id in this js file :

```
const y = document.querySelector("#sib-form");
y.addEventListener("submit", (e => { e.preventDefault();....
```

So that the 2 forms can work on the same page, i have changed the js this way, but it didn t solve the issue:

```html
<form class="sibform_snpt" id="sib-form" method="POST" action="https://45ff9c8b.sibforms.com/serve/MUXXXX" data-type="subscription">
```

```
const y_forms = document.querySelectorAll('.sibform_snpt');
for (let i = 0; i < y_forms.length; i++) {
     y= form[i];
     y.setAttribute("novalidate", "true"),
     y.addEventListener("submit", (e => { e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

On Brevo help website I found that you need to use iFrames to display multiple forms on the same page:
https://help.brevo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019846960-Create-a-subscription-form-Troubleshooting-FAQ
[https://help.brevo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019846960-Create-a-subscription-form-Troubleshooting-FAQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgyIQ.png)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, instead copy over the relevant potions of the link to your answer.